# Area highlight mouseout

Tags: jquery

I have the following function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("img[usemap]").mapify();

$(window).resize(function(){

  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#map area").eq(1).trigger("mouseenter.mapify").trigger("focus.mapify").trigger("touchend.mapify");
    $(".mapify-svg polygon").eq(1).css("stroke","#09f");
  },5000);

}).resize();
</script>
```

This functions highlights a specific area (using [mapify](https://github.com/etienne-martin/Mapify)) after 5 seconds using a stroke.

This is completely functional but I can't seem to find a way to adapt the function to include a `mouseout` functionality.

Basically, I need that after 5 seconds the area highlights, it stays highlighted for 2 seconds and then it goes out again, repeating itself.

I'm fairly new to JS and image mapping but I can provide any additional information that might help.

The project I'm working on is located at [https://sporedev.ro/pleiade](http://sporedev.ro/pleiade).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following

```
function blinkIn() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#map area").eq(1).trigger("mouseenter.mapify").trigger("focus.mapify").trigger("touchend.mapify");
    $(".mapify-svg polygon").eq(1).css("stroke", "#09f");
    blinkOut();
  }, 5000);
}

function blinkOut() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#map area").eq(1).trigger('mouseout.mapify');
    blinkIn();
  }, 2000);
}

blinkIn();
```

But do not put in the `.resize` handler as that will fire multiple times while resizing and mess it up.

Comment: Thank you! It works but for some reason instead of disappearing when mouseout is triggered it makes a weird outline. Would really appreciate if you could check https://sporedev.ro/pleiade/ and look at the second statue (you have to wait 3s) and let me know if you have any idea why. :)